# rmagick install error ubunutu 16.04 ruby 2.4.0p0

Tags: ruby

I tried to install rmagick using these commands, but it doesn't work.

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
sudo apt-get install imagemagick libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev
sudo gem install rmagick
```

It ended up with the following error.

> Building native extensions.
>   This could take a while...
>   ERROR: Error installing rmagick:
>   ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>   current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rmagick-2.16.0/ext/RMagick /usr/bin/ruby2.3
>   -r ./siteconf20170603-20826-3to4j3.rb extconf.rb
>   mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h
>   extconf failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rmagick-2.16.0 for inspection.
>   Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/rmagick-2.16.0/gem_make.out

Answer (score 0):

You need to install also the *ruby-dev* package. That is why the ruby.h is not found when compiling a native extension.

Use the following command to install it.

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```

Basing on the package description, that will install the *ruby2.3-dev* package. That was the package it installed on my Ubuntu 16.04.

> Package: ruby-dev
>   State: not installed
>   Multi-Arch: same
>   Version: 2:2.3.0+1bbox1~xenial1
>   Priority: optional
>   Section: devel
>   Maintainer: Antonio Terceiro 
>   Architecture: amd64
>   Uncompressed Size: 20.5 k
>   Depends: ruby2.3-dev
>   Provided by: ruby1.8-dev (1:1.8.7.375-1bbox1~xenial2)
>   Description: Header files for compiling extension modules for Ruby (default version)  Ruby is the interpreted scripting language for quick and easy object-oriented programming.  It has many features to process text files  and to do system management tasks (as in perl).  It is simple, straight-forward, and extensible. This package contains the header files and the mkmf library,  **necessary to make extension library for Ruby**. It is **also required to build  many gems**. This package is a dependency package, which depends on Debian's default Ruby version (**currently v2.3**).

I then installed Ruby 2.4, so now that package doesn't result installed on my computer.